# New mount path is getting created for external drive after reboot

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

I have an external drive connected to my rpi 4 which has the label "4". Sometimes the device completely hangs and I take out the power cable and put it back in to restart, not sure if there's a better way to do this. I have noticed when I do this my external gets mounted under a new path /media/pi/4(n). The page seems to change every time this happens. How can I fix this? Here's a screenshot of the directory /media/pi, currently it's mounted under 42. I want it to be always 4 so that my settings don't break in multiple locations.

[image]

Comment: Disable the PCManFM automounter and that stuff will stop happening.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5014688).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to "fix" this is to unmount properly, and preferably use a different USB port.

This is just the way the automount "feature" works - it has no way of knowing if this is the same drive or another.

The best (and traditional) way of automounting is to create a `etc/fstab` entry, identifying the drive - preferably by `UUID`.

My `etc/fstab` is listed below (although I use `noauto` as I prefer to mount manually).

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=b5d2de0f-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=b5d2de0f-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
UUID=94dc6686-0eda-41ba-87f7-494d7e37f913       /mnt/PiData     ext4    defaults,noatime,noauto  0     0
UUID=4AF49046F4903663       /mnt/SeagateBackupPlus     ntfs    ro,noauto,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8 0   0
UUID=4AF49046F4903663       /mnt/SeagateNTFS     ntfs    rw,noauto,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8   0   0
UUID=2dd6c96e-4655-4a04-a8ca-7a5fd39d09bb       /mnt/PiHDD     ext4    defaults,noatime,noauto  0     0

# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved the naming problem was to give the USB Stick a name (e.g. while formatting it on Windows)

So now every time my code (python) search and finds a given name it knows it is that specific USB Stick. The path to it is then `/media/pi/MyUSBstickName` .